# cannot map from one entity to another automapper exception throwing?

Tags: c#

I have tried to get from resources from database and tried to map to another model class but was unable to do .and it is showing an automapper exception.

> Trying to map
>   RM.Easicreate.Data.Entities.Resource
>   to
>   RM.Easicreate.Core.DataContracts.ResourceDataContract.
>   Exception of type
>   'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException'
>   was thrown.

My code looks like this.

```
Resource res= resources.FirstOrDefault();
ResourceDataContract r = Mapper.Map<Resource, ResourceDataContract>(res);
```

and i have configured automapper in my bootstaper like this

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Resource, ResourceDataContract>();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

but it seems to be not working? why is that so?

Comment: Can you post the compete exception. If you are using Entity Framework the object returned looks like a real object it it is more of a proxy which Automapper has problem mapping.

Comment: Where is WCF in the picture (one of the tags of the question)?

Comment: @carlosfigueira:-yes man

Answer (score 0):

If there is no data in your table FirstOrDefault will return null, not 100% sure but sending in a null value may give that exception.

Comment: yaar, i've resolved it. actually i was creating an service installer. What i have missed is to Configure the automapper at the constructor.